# Locking with timeout pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, timeout, locking

`lock` uses this pattern

```
if(Monitor.Enter(lock))
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    finally { Monitor.Exit(lock); } // using this style to reduce post "height"
```

if we don't want to wait infinite we can provide timeout

```
if(!Monitor.TryEnter(lock, timeout))
    throw new TimeoutException();
try
{
    ...
}
finally { Monitor.Exit(lock); }
```

I have scenario when method has to obtain multiple locks before it start doing anything. This looks awful:

```
if(!Monitor.TryEnter(lockA, timeout))
    throw new TimeoutException();
try
{
    if(!Monitor.TryEnter(lockB, timeout))
        throw new TimeoutException();
    try
    {
        if(!Monitor.TryEnter(lockC, timeout))
            throw new TimeoutException();
        try
        {
            ... // more of such constructions
        }
        finally { Monitor.Exit(lockC); }
    }
    finally { Monitor.Exit(lockB); }
}
finally { Monitor.Exit(lockA); }
```

It has problems:

- looks ugly (the method code is indented, imagine how it will looks for `lockZ`), can be solved by putting method code into another method.
- locking occurs synchronously, so the worst successful case may take time slightly less than a sum of all timeouts.

Is there a way to improve this timeout pattern?

I was thinking to make a method with delegate parameter and lock to achieve something like linq chaining (but to also run locks in parallel, this is a challenge):

```
Lock(lockA).Lock(lockB).Lock(lockC).Run( () => ...);
```

Or perhaps there is another way?

Answer (score 11):

I would go with usings for sync lock:

```
using System;
using System.Threading; 

public class MyLock : IDisposable
{
    private object lockObj;

    public MyLock(object lockObj, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        this.lockObj = lockObj;
        if (!Monitor.TryEnter(this.lockObj, timeout))
            throw new TimeoutException();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using(new MyLock(lockA, new TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
using(new MyLock(lockB, new TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)))
using(new MyLock(lockC, new TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)))
{
    // your code
}
```

Do not know if "locking" in ctor is good pattern / design, but it will work ;)

For async. parallelization is not good idea. Why?
If some thread will enter the monitor, the same thread must leave it (exit with lock). So if you lock on `objA` within `Parallel.ForEach` (f.e.) you will not know which thread has done it. So you won't be able to release it.

Comment: Locking in ctor definitely is a well spread pattern, especially in C++. It's called RAII.