# Chaining locks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

When trying to answer the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37961521/locking-with-timeout-pattern/37962449#37962449), I wrote this piece of code :

```
using static MyNameSpace.Locker; //So that we don't need to specify the static class name before each call.
public class MainClass
{
    public MainMethod()
    {
        Lock(new object()).Lock(new object()).RunAction(() => Console.WriteLine("Finished"));
    }
}


public static class Locker
{
    public static async Task<List<object>> Lock(object toLock, int timeout = -1)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => TryEnter(toLock, timeout));
        return new List<object>() { toLock };
    }

    public static async Task<List<object>> Lock(
        this Task<List<object>> lockedChain,
        object toLock,
        int timeout = -1)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => TryEnter(toLock, timeout));
        await lockedChain;
        lockedChain.Result.Add(toLock)
        return lockedChain.Result;
    }

    public static async void RunAction(this Task<List<object>> lockChain, Action toRun)
    {
        await lockChain;
        try
        {
            toRun.Invoke();
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (var chainMember in lockChain.Result)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(chainMember);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void TryEnter(object toLock, int timeout = -1)
    {
        var success = false;
        if (timeout > 0)
        {
            success = Monitor.TryEnter(toLock, timeout);
        }
        else
        {
            success = Monitor.TryEnter(toLock);
        }

        if (!success)
        {
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }
    }
}
```

But as some user rightfully remarked, this won't work for a very simple reason : Since the methods are async, they may not run on the same thread, thus throwing an exception when trying to release the Monitor.

How would one go to ensure the `Enter` and `Exit` method of the monitor a run on the same thread ?

Comment: Locks are the antithesis of concurrent programming. The whole point of async/await, TPL, Dataflow, Reactive is to *avoid* locks, not reintroduce them. In any case, Stephen Toub published a series of [asynchronous coordination primitives](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx)  a while ago which use TaskCompletionSource tosignal completion and can be awaited with  `Task.WhenAll` or `Task.WaitAll`. No need to chain

Comment: Although, with tasks, simply running whatever needs to run in parallel and awaiting on all tasks with `await Task.WhenAll()` is enough

Comment: This question is a follow-up of the linked question. Would if be possible to actually chain methods so that timed-out locks needed for an operation would be awaited together instead of one after another ?

Comment: The original question asked about something different. You don't need to chain locks for asynchronous *coordination* though . You can wait for multiple tasks at the same time. You can create *asynchronous coordination* primitives like an async lock and Stephen Toub has done so.  It's better to use purpose-built libraries though like Dataflow or Rx, instead of trying to build them from scratch

Comment: Not arguing against that, just wanted to try out the Linq Like syntax the Author or the linked question "suggested", I'm not bold enough to try to redo something that was done, tried and approved. Just wanted to know if this was possible using this syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of forcing the lock operations onto the same thread which is nearly impossible, use a lock that is not thread-affine: `SemaphoreSlim`. It has native async support as well (as opposed to blocking).

In the original question that you linked to I'd go with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37961742/122718) instead. Seems cleaner than the chain solution which contains a lot of artificial complexity. Code quality is not so much about the specific call syntax being used. Just by putting things in a syntactic chain you cannot reduce complexity much.

In particular the chain solution is just a complicated way of saying `Lock(new [] { lock1, lock2 }, () => ...);` I think. All the chain does it build up a list. `using` makes this even simpler because it does away with the lambda. Lambdas are less composable because you can't return from the lambda like you can from `using`. I think you should target this:

```
using (MultiLock(new [] { lock1, lock2 }, timeout)) {
 //...
}
```

Comment: I'd go to with the suggested answer, this was only a "What-if" question. Thanks for suggesting the SemaphoreSlim, it gave me some ideas on how to resolve the problem. I won't push this anymore though since it was only curiosity and not an actual need :)