# Queue threads to wait for data fetched over HTTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, http, locking

I am working on a web page that will let its users administer their account.
A request to do something might look like this:

`Browser -> Web Server -> API`, where each arrow is an HTTP request.

When accessing the API, I need an access token. This token is not user specific, but belongs to the site as a whole. When a user wants to do something, this token might not be present. If so, I need to fetch it. When fetching it, other users might want to do something, and also discovers that the token is not present. Since the request to get the access token is underway, I want to make the users wait for the request fetching the access token to return, then use the access token when the request is complete.

The trouble is that I need some way to make the process for each user wait for the call initiated by the first user to return. It might be possible to do something like this (the access token will be stored in the Application State):

```
lock (lockObj) {
    if (hasAccessToken)
        return GetResponseFromApplicationState().accessToken;

    var response = FetchAccessToken();
    SaveResponseInApplicationState(response);

    return response.accessToken;
}
```

`lock`, as I understand, would queue up the threads. However, I don't like the idea of having a HTTP request inside a lock block, since it might deadlock if the request never returns, or something like that. Perhaps I could set a timeout on the `lock`, but I'm not sure about this.

How can I solve this? Can I somehow queue the processes for each user?

Comment: a deadlock is when multiple operations are all waiting on each other.  Something that takes out a lock and just doesn't finish isn't a deadlock.  Additionally, pretty much any HTTP querying operation is going to have a timeout, so it won't run forever if you don't want it to, and of course you can add your own if it doesn't already have one (which is unlikely).

Comment: @Servy I see :) Maybe I'll try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37961742/1211119

Comment: Like I said, you almost certainly don't need to actually do that, and it doesn't even look like that's what you want to do either.

Comment: @Servy So just lock, and rely on HTTP to timeout by itself?

Comment: If you've made sure you have a desirable timeout time, yes.

Comment: @Servy Alright, thanks for your help!